# How can I populate more than one select elements with one javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, dropdown

I have following html:

Products:

```html
Products:<br/>
<select id="options" title="options" name="options"></select><br/>
<select id="options1" title="options" name="options"></select><br/>
<select id="options2" title="options" name="options"></select><br/>
```

And I have a javascript function which finds data from database using jquery ajax for these select elements. How can I place that data in all these select elements at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `options` is a list of `<option>` elements that came from the server or was built with data coming back from the server:

```
$('[name=options').append(options);
```

Comment: Thanks Rob M, for the answer, I used the following code which worked:

$("[name='options']").append(newOption);